# error when trying to loop through grouped entries according to dropdown field

Tags: categories, forloop, group, drop-down, craft.entries

I was trying to follow [this example](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/filters#group) from stack overflow to loop through a list of entries and output them by a custom dropdown field

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('resource').find() %}
{% set allEntriesByCat = allEntries|group('entry.resourceType') %}
{% for cat, entriesInCat in allEntriesByCat %}
    <h2>{{cat}}</h2>
    {% for entry in entriesInCat %}
        <article class="resource">
            <h3 class="resource__name"><a class="resource__link" href="{{entry.resourceLink}}">{{entry.title}}</a></h3>
            <div class="resource__content">{{entry.resourceContent}}</div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But if I do that, I get the error: `Internal Server Error
Craft\EntryModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "entry".`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `entry` from your `entry.resourceType`

```
{% set allEntriesByCat = allEntries|group('resourceType') %}
```

will work